# Embed player with mixed content

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'm stuck in a project where I was told to use youtube videos in the website. Using the youtube API to get channels, playlists and videos are all okay. But when I take an IFrame to show the video/playlist the browser console keeps warning me that a mixed content was blocked.[See the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmTCq.png).

I've already changed http: // website to // website within my website files. It seems to be a Google font, but I cannot figure out how to troubleshot this problem.

Comment: Your Console error is partially in portuguese, I believe is a good idea to post a translation for it, that way a wider range of people may be able to help. In the error output there is an "Lear More" link, did you try that?

Comment: Can you also try to fetch those icons with "https" instead of "http"? You can also have a look on the network tab to see the response code/body of that request

Comment: I did that, but as far as I know the load of mixed content is allowed for localhost. The IFrame src is set to //youtube.com... and it seems to have no effect. My network tab shows that these imports are not secure but they return 200 response.